# passing input value of form in zend framework

Tags: php, html, forms, zend-framework

I want to pass input variable to a controller and a action , I've tried here but it cannot specify phone number which user already inserted .

```
<form class= "search-phone" action="" method="get">
        <p>phone number:</p>
             <input type="text" name="phone" />
            <a class="button-link" href="<?php echo $this->url(
            array(
                'controller' => 'books',
                'action'     => 'search',
                 'search_id' => $'_GET[phone]'
            ),
            'default',
            true) ?>">search
        </a>

</form>
```

Comment: You can use Zend_Form for better form managment - http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to use the `<form>` element's action to submit the contents of the input's within the form (unless you're using ajax or are in need of a special interruption/task before the submit of the form).  You're anchor link is just directing you to a url. And your form should be posting as the method, not getting.  The form element should look something like this:

```
<form class="search-phone" action="controller_name/action_name/or_however_you_get_to_your_action" method="POST">
```

And then you have to add a submit button.  Then in your action in your controller, you want to get whatever is posted, something like this:

```
action_name() {
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; 
}
```

where 'phone' corresponds to the element's value whose name is "phone".

hoep this helps

Comment: @afn: Apologies, should be $_POST['phone'].  I'll change that in my answer. see if that helps.